# how to change prop function to use option

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have the follwing code:

```
 if( $('option[name=status]').prop(apr1) )
       {selectsatus = 'apr1';}
```

if the select option = status write $_POST['slectstatus']; to be result

the prop() function is for using checked value to check if the value is checked with what to change it so the function will become to work if option name = status and the selection from this option is result to write in the variable selectstatus this same result ?

```
<select>
  <option name="status" value="apr1">Apr1</option>
  <option name="status" value="apr2">Apr2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What? I'm lost reading the question, could you clarify?

Comment: Where does the "aprobado" value come from?

Comment: `<option>` tags do **NOT** have a `name` attribute. Your html is fundamentally broken.

Comment: I want to change the function .prop() to something else that will check if the name="status" have value="apr1" to make the following {selectsatus = 'apr1';}  , I did changed the code in the question so now it is more clear.

Comment: Marc B what do you suggest to be able select the option value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do, all you need is this:

```
<select name="status" >
  <option value="apr1">Apr1</option>
  <option value="apr2">Apr2</option>
</select>
```

```
selectsatus = $("select[name=status]").val();
```

This will get the selected value of the dropdown.